# I want to save two entities in one transaction with JPA if any error occure while inserting the data the changes should be rolled back

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

for example i have two entities: first is student and another is address. i want to insert data on both tables with foreign key relationship, but their is one condition: if any error occurs while inserting the data in any tables the all changes should be roll back.

how can i do please help

```
class Student{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   private String firstName;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="address_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Address address;
}

class Address {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   private String city;

}

@Service
public class StudentService {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo studentRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private AddressRepo addressRepo;

    public Student createStudent(StudentRequest studentRequest) {
        
        Student student=new Student(studentRequest);
        
        Address address=new Address();
        
        address.setCity(studentRequest.getCity());
        address.setStreet(studentRequest.getStreet());
        address=addressRepo.save(address);
        
        student.setAddress(address);
        
        student=studentRepo.save(student);
        
        return student;
        
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the annotation @Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Stateless EJB :

```
@Stateless
public StudentDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Student createStudent(StudentRequest studentRequest) {

        Student student=new Student(studentRequest);

        Address address=new Address();

        address.setCity(studentRequest.getCity());
        address.setStreet(studentRequest.getStreet());
        em.persist(address);

        student.setAddress(address);
        em.persist(student);

        return student;

    }    
}
```

Comment: i want to do by jpa?can you go through my code one more time

Comment: This is JPA : EntityManager is javax.persistence.EntityManager

Comment: I have editied my code with your example. But it looks like you don't use EJB Stateless.

Comment: i want to know if address is persist after that exception occure in saving student the persist object of address will be rolled back or not?

Comment: Doesn’t the createStudent need a @transaction annotation to be wrapped in one?

Comment: Default is TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED. That means once you enter createStudent you are in a transaction. If there is a problem, the client must catch EJBException to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general question, so I will try to point you in the right direction. For this I assume:

- you are using `spring-data-jpa`
- you have a datasource already configured
- your application starts up correctly
- you already configured the `@Repository` or you know how to use the `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceContext`
- I will assume the `Repository` solution

The good news is: Persisting objects that are marked using `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` and `ManyToMany` is a core feature, so most of this is already handled by JPA/Hibernate. All you have to ensure is that you *read the documentation* and *follow it*.

First step is to understand `Cascading`. Cascading is *not* turned on by default. There are tons of resources on the web, that help you understand this, I will point you to [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types). This means that you will need to set the `cascade` attribute on the `OneToOne` annotation (see referenced tutorial).

`Student.java`

```java
class Student{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   private String firstName;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="address_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Address address;
}
```

Then, using a normal `@Repository`:

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

Now you have correctly working mapping and the repository.

Once you have done this, you should be ready to roll, given the above assumptions hold. You can now write a small testcase for a student, e.g.

```java
@DataJpaTest
class StudentRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@Autowired
private AddressRepository addressRepository;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    assumeThat(studentRepository).isNotNull();
    assumeThat(addressRepository).isNotNull();
}

@Test
void testSaveStudent {
   assumeThat(studentRepository.count()).isZero();
   assumeThat(addressRepository.count()).isZero();
   var student = new Student();
   var address = new Address();
   address.setCity("New York");
   student.setFirstName("Max");
   student.setAddress(address);
   studentRepository.save(student);
   assertThat(studentRepository.count()).isOne();
   assertThat(addressRepository.count()).isOne();
}
```

Second: In regards to your transaction question. Per default when you invoke a repository's `save` method a transaction is started. So in the very base case you don't necessarily need a transaction. Although, once you deal with more complex business cases it's necessary to understand JPA's transaction manager. Transactions usually happen on the service layer. See links below for more info on Transactions.

```java
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class StudentService {
   @Autowired
   private StudentRepository studentRepository;

   @Transactional
   public Student assignStudentToAddress(Student s, Address a) {
      s.setAddress(a);
      return studentRepository.save(s);
   }
}
```

Some thoughts:

- Are you sure that one student can only stay at one address? This would mean that living arrangements like in Big Bang Theory (shared apartment) wouldn't work. For testing purposes this works of course.
- Consider the reverse: what if we have an address screen and we want to add students to it?

More resources:

- Beginner's guide to mapping [by VladMihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)
- Mapping `OneToOne` beginner friendly: [by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one) and slightly more advanced [by VladMihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- Mapping `OneToMany` beginner friendly: [by baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) and slightly more advanced: [by VladMihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- Using `Transactional` [by VladMihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-transactional-annotation/) and [by MarcoBehler](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)

Comment: i am not understading what you trying to say? can you please go thorugh my code one more time?

Comment: Please go through my extensive answer one more time, I actually provided you with a service, utilizing JPA with Transactional in my code. If you have troubles understanding the stack I HIGHLY recommend studying the provided tutorials and additionally reading through the official documentation and ask specific questions where troubles arise.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can look through the updates, I also included code to show you exactly how to setup the mapping and the repository. My answer always included the service and the test case. From here you should have no issues anymore.

Comment: now tell me what is assumeThat method and where you declared?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: assertj - testing framework included with spring-boot-starter-test